# What is the CDSU for a governor with magnetic trim?

Tags: aircraft-systems

[image]

The governor is a spring-loaded, flyweight-operated, hydraulic control valve whose driving gear is in mesh with the differential output ring gear through the scavenge pump gear. The governor senses CSDU output speed and controls the oil pressure to the control cylinder, maintaining a constant output speed of 12,000 revolutions per minute.

This I have understood from this picture but I want to know the operation in detail.

**What is the purpose of the CSDU?**

Comment: Please explain what the acronym CSDU means. Please add some background information on where in an aircraft it is found. Please add reference to your image: where did you find it?

Comment: sorry I just rephrased the question, the thing is in my book it is not a detailed explanation of how it works.

Comment: The CSDU function is to maintain the alternator constant speed by adjusting oil pressure when the engine RPM change. The flyweights are moving a swashplate not shown here. The magnetic coil is used to include the electric load into the regulation loop, as a high current will slow the alternator regardless of the engine speed. You can find the rest starting page 1-34 of [Avionics In Plain English](https://books.google.com/books?id=0UXJBAAAQBAJ&pg=SA1-PA34&lpg=SA1-PA34). Refine your question if needed after your have read this section.

Comment: thanks a lot, and will keep that in mind next time i have a question

Comment: I find it quite hard sometimes to understand procedures here. There is a question on an aviation related subject. The OP-er is asked to provide more detail, which he does. A concise answer is given in a comment, proving that the question is narrow enough to be answered by someone on this forum. And then the question is closed as too broad.

Comment: @Koyovis: The question first was "explain this mechanism", so the closure for being too broad. Then the question was refined, but for me still too broad. After the OP has a better understanding (e.g. by reading the section linked), if they are still missing something then they can edit and reopen, a request which I think will be supported by anybody and full answers could be provided. I believe this was managed correctly, and I agree this is a good topic (there was no need to downvote).

Comment: @mins Just wondering about the timing, the question was closed after your informative comment, which would have made a great answer by the way.

Comment: @abdulla - I've made a small edit that I think pulls out your main question. Please feel to clarify further from there if that's not what you're after. If this is what OP is after, then this is now a pretty focused question that can be reopened

Comment: Please reopen this question. After the edit it has a nice answer :-)

Comment: the question is open for comments and answer, @FreeMan, when I asked the question It was because the knowledge I had was limited and I wanted to know understand more about the diagram

Comment: and thanks for the answer @mins,